# Has there ever been a US airport with identifier PM2?

Tags: airport, usa

I have an old entry in my logbook having landed and departed from an airport with identifier PM2. I think I either can't read my handwriting or I made a mistake because I can find no record of such an airport ever existing. Does anyone have a way of finding out?

Comment: It's probably a mistake or bad writing.  Could it be PMZ (KPMZ) in Plymouth NC?  It would help if you could narrow it down geographically.  What was the origin of the flight to it and the destination when departing it?

Comment: To expand on Gerry, If you have the flight time and departure/arrival airports, and type of plane, it would help narrow it down a lot.

Comment: I think it's PMZ. On 8/6/08 I flew in a 172 from MAO to PM2/PMZ with a duration of 1.8. Then PM2/PMZ to EQY with a duration of 2.2. So I think that solves the mystery.

Comment: Here was the flight that day assuming KPMZ. https://skyvector.com/?ll=30.27677933896586,-81.80566405639985&chart=301&zoom=12&fpl=%20KHEG%20KMAO%20KPMZ%20KEQY%20KHEG

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. PM2 would not be a valid ID in the FAA system. According to the [FAA order defining the system](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/7350.9_w_Change_1_Loc_Id.pdf):

> 1−2−7. ASSIGNMENT SYSTEM §c. Most one−number, two−letter identifiers have been assigned to aviation weather reporting and observation stations and special−use locations. Some of these identifiers may be assigned to public−use landing facilities within the United States and its jurisdictions, which do not meet the requirements for identifiers in the three−letter series. In this identifier series, **the number is always in the first position of the three−character combination**.
>   <sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

So two letters followed by a number is not a valid ID.

Comment: Can you provide a FAA number and/or link for said order?

Comment: @UnrecognizedFallingObject Aw dangit! That was supposed to be a link. Gimme a minute and I’ll put it in.